# To check wether a given string seqence is palindrome or not using stacks

Tags: c, palindrome, stack

I want to know how to store the characters or integers popped from stack to be stored so that I can compare it with the original string or int value.

For example :

```
n = 1221;
n = n / 1000; // so that i get the last digit in this case 1 and dividing the remainder 
              // further each time by 100, 10 and 1
```

If I store each number that I get in a variable-- for example, say that I store 1 which I got from the above division in a variable named s, and push it onto the stack.
After this, I pop the values back out; when I do so, how can I check weather it is equal to the original number? I can check it with a if condition, for eg if i have 3 did then

```
(i == p && check for other two numbers)
```

but i don`t want that i want to check for any size number.

Please don't send the source code on how to do it, just give me a few snippets or a few hints, thanks. Also please let me know how you came up for the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: no one cares about palindromes except in classrooms. ;)

Comment: :) I know, hey what kind of programming would one do,in the office or a company? Does it involve all this like finding sum of natural numbers or checking for expressions correctness and all that?

Comment: After 25+ years in the business, I have never once been asked to sum natural numbers or check expressions for correctness, so I'd say no.  (But the compiler development guys would probably have a different answer on the checking for correctness thing.)

Answer (score 2):

> Dont send the source code on how to do it

ok ;)

> just give me few snippets or few hints

*[Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064082/to-check-wether-a-given-string-seqence-is-palindrome-or-not-using-stacks)*

> and while you give the solution let me know how you came up for the solution, weather you had seen a program like this or know the algorithm or came up with a solution now when you saw the question. Thanks

i have been doing this too long to remember where i first saw it =\

Comment: uhh... well, here's the wikipedia article on recursion: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve the problem, like Justin mentioned.
Once you start your recursion you will divide the number with an appropriate divisor(1000,100,10,1) store the quotient in the stack. You do this till the end.
Once you reach the 'unit' place, you store the unit digit, and now start popping out of the stack. 
Have an if-else ladder to return an integer from the recursive function.
The ladder will have conditions of returning the int after left shifting and returning the variable shifted.
You can do your check in the main function.

```
1             ->1221(left shift 122 OR with 1)
  2          ->122(left shift 12 OR with 2)
    2       ->12(left shift 1 OR with 2)
      1---->1
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks
Aditya